# Node.js and rails app hosting with a shared MongoDB database and pricing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, mongodb, heroku

I have been experimenting a lot with node.js as well as with rails and mongoDB lately. I'd like to know if there's any hosting options out there where I can deploy my apps written in rails and node.js which will share a same MongoDB database?

My rails app will do most of the writing to the mongoDB instance, while the node.js app will only fetch(read) the data from there.

I have heard about heroku, but it seems that it's more focus on mid-large scale deployment while I'm currently only looking for a simple small deployment since this would only be for personal use, and I dont expect too many visitors anyway. I've also heard that Heroku is available for free under certain condition.. Is this true? Also, is google app engine an option for me?

Would like to hear from people who have experience hosting their personal rails/node.js apps with heroku or any other hosting options, including shared hosting as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, is google app engine an option for me?

App Engine is kind of its own little world, so you can't install MongoDB on app engine.

> Would like to hear from people who have experience hosting their personal rails/node.js apps with heroku or any other hosting options, including shared hosting as well.

Honestly, for small apps, the other option is simply to buy a small VPS. Places like Linode sell them for $20 / month with full access.

You can also use Amazon AWS. They have a [free tier for new](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#pricing) customers. You can also buy a reserved "Micro" for $23 / year (if you pay in advance). Of course, Amazon will nickel and dime you for everything, so it will probably be more than that. It should stay under $10 / month though. Of course, there are other competitors here like Rackspace.

If you don't want to host the DB, you can also use MongoLab or MongoHQ and pick your cloud provider. They generally offer to host your data in the same DC as your provider.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.heroku.com/pricing

Hosting free for 1 dyno and 5Mb postgresql shared database. There are two mongo addons, with free 240Mb database. Perfect for a small deployment and tests :)